# Rust. Изменение очереди двумя потоками

Tags: многопоточность, очередь, rust

Имеется очередь с методами push и pop. Хочу сделать так, чтобы два потока могли к ней обращаться и применять эти методы.

```
    pub struct Queue 
{
    data: std::collections::VecDeque<u8>,
}

impl Queue
{
    pub fn push(&mut self, val: u8)
    {
        self.data.push_back(val);
    } 

    pub fn pop(&mut self)
    {
        if !self.data.is_empty()
        {
            self.data.pop_front();
        }
    } 

    pub fn front(&self) -> u8
    {
        *self.data.front().unwrap()
    }
}
```

Функция обработки:

```
fn processing(i_b: &mut Arc<RefCell<Queue>>, o_b: &mut Arc<RefCell<Queue>>)
    {
        i_b.get_mut().pop();
        print!("{}, {} : ", i_b.get_mut().front(), o_b.get_mut().front());
    }
```

Обернул передаваемые параметры в Arc и RefCell, однако, как я понял, RefCell не является Sync и потому не может использоваться в параллельности. Что нужно использовать? Читал про каналы, но вроде как моя ситуация не подходит под это. Попытался вставить мьютексы, но вроде тоже не помогло

```
error[E0277]: `std::cell::RefCell<Queue>` cannot be shared between threads safely
  --> src\main.rs:69:14
   |
69 |     let _c = thread::spawn(move || {
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `std::cell::RefCell<Queue>` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `std::cell::RefCell<Queue>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::sync::Arc<std::cell::RefCell<Queue>>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src\main.rs:69:28: 71:6 _a:std::sync::Arc<std::cell::RefCell<Queue>>, _b:std::sync::Arc<std::cell::RefCell<Queue>>]`
   = note: required by `std::thread::spawn`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По порядку:

1) Рекомендуется использовать готовую библиотеку [`crossbeam-queue`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.7.1/crossbeam/queue/index.html) с реализацией конкурентных MPMC очередей на Rust: https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam-queue
Она предоставляет 2 типа очередей: [ограниченные](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.7.1/crossbeam/queue/struct.ArrayQueue.html) и [неограниченные](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.7.1/crossbeam/queue/struct.SegQueue.html) по размеру. В зависимости от условий вашей задачи можете использовать наиболее подходящую. Обе очереди реализуют `Send` и `Sync` и имеют возможность создавать неограниченное число продюсеров и консьюмеров. Стоит отметить они имеют отличное от стандартного VecDeque API.

Пример:

```rust
use crossbeam_queue::SegQueue;
use std::thread::spawn;
use std::sync::Arc;

fn main() {
    let q = Arc::new(SegQueue::new());
    q.push(0);
    q.push(1);
    let threads = vec![
        spawn({
            let q = Arc::clone(&q);
            move || {
                println!("{:?}", q.pop());
            }
        }),
        spawn({
            let q = Arc::clone(&q);
            move || {
                q.push(5);
            }
        }),
    ];
    for thread in threads {
        let _ = thread.join();
    }
}
```

Ссылка на пример: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=747d5553324e8edff52d3f56fc765001

Так же здесь можно посмотреть примеры использования: https://github.com/crossbeam-rs/crossbeam/blob/master/crossbeam-queue/tests/seg_queue.rs

2) Для решения данной задачи вы можете так же использовать и стандартные примитивы синхронизации `Mutex`, `RwLock`. Приведу пример с `RwLock`:

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};
use std::thread::spawn;

pub struct Queue {
    pub data: RwLock<VecDeque<u8>>,
}

impl Queue {
    pub fn push(&self, val: u8) {
        let mut data = self.data.write().unwrap();
        data.push_back(val);
    }

    pub fn pop(&self) -> Option<u8> {
        let is_empty = {
            let data = self.data.read().unwrap();
            data.is_empty()
        };
        if !is_empty {
            let mut data = self.data.write().unwrap();
            data.pop_front()
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    pub fn front(&self) -> Option<u8> {
        let data = self.data.read().unwrap();
        data.front().cloned()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut q = VecDeque::new();
    q.push_back(0);
    q.push_back(1);
    let q = Arc::new(Queue {
        data: RwLock::new(q),
    });
    let threads = vec![
        spawn({
            let q = Arc::clone(&q);
            move || {
                println!("{:?}", q.front());
            }
        }),
        spawn({
            let q = Arc::clone(&q);
            move || {
                q.push(5);
            }
        }),
    ];
    for thread in threads {
        let _ = thread.join();
    }
}
```

Ссылка на пример: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bb03e545eec57a445803ef97fce51646

3) `RefCell` не является контейнером для синхронизации доступа. Это контейнер предназначенный для реализации [`interior mutability`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) (когда необходимо перенести проверки изменяемости чего-либо в рантайм) для не-`Copy` типов.

4) К сожалению я не могу сказать, что у вас не получилось с `Mutex` так как предоставленная ошибка компилятора относится к использованию `RefCell`.

Comment: Ох, сколько способов оказывается есть. Спасибо большое. Можно тогда ещё уточняющий вопрос: т.е, как я понял, refcell можно использовать, только если данные будут меняться в одном потоке?

Comment: Вы всё правильно поняли.